# Parse Subclass Instance Method EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, exc-bad-access, exc-bad-instruction

When subclassing from a parse user object `PFUser`, I get bad-instruction errors when using my own methods. Do you guys have any thoughts on why this is happening

**User.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class User: PFUser {

    // Instance Variables
    @NSManaged var photo: PFFile

    // Parse Setup
    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    // Instance Methods
    func fetchPhoto(callback: (image: UIImage) -> Void) {
        guard let url = self.photo.url else {
            return
        }

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

        if let image = Globals.imageCache.imageForRequest(request) {
            callback(image: image)
            return
        }

        Globals.imageDownloader.downloadImage(URLRequest: request) { response in
            if let image: UIImage = response.result.value {
                callback(image: image)

                Globals.imageCache.addImage(image, forRequest: request)
            } else {
                print(response)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

import UIKit

```
class ProfileHeaderController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var avatarButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    private var user = User.current()

    func updateHeader() {
        self.userLabel.text = self.user.username
        self.nameLabel.text = self.user.fullName

        self.user.fetchPhoto { (image) -> Void in
            self.avatarButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to overwrite a method or add new method ?

Comment: Why are you force unwrapping the image data?  Try checking for nil and log any error conditions

Comment: @GovindaraoKondala im trying to access a new method I wrote

Comment: @Paulw11 I posted the wrong method `uploadPhoto` in the User.swift class. I have updated it to show the method I am referring to `fetchPhoto`.

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?  Set an exception breakpoint or set a breakpoint in your `imageForRequest` and/or `downloadImage` functions and step through.

Comment: @Paulw11 its on this line `self.user.fetchPhoto `

Comment: @Paulw11 figured it out! Just needed to register the subclass before initializing Parse

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to register the subclass in your Appdelegate or before you call Parse.setApplicationId

its stated in this block of text: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses

example:

```
Appdelegate.swift
....
User.registerSubclass()
Parse.setApplicationId("appid", clientId:"clientid")
```